# Android Combine 2 Lists of data one from Room LiveData and 1 from Observable

Tags: android, rx-java, retrofit, android-room

I am building an app that for now have one main data model `Character`, I'm using Room as local DB and retrofit2 for API calls.
The user can set a Character as favorite and when this happens this character is stored in local DB (only local DB know about favorite characters of a current user, this app does not store any data on remote servers just use API to get a list of characters).
The question is when user load next time the app how to load the list from web and from local DB (Room return `LiveData<List<Character>`) and filter out from web list `Characters` which stored in local DB with the help of RxJava2 (I can use Observable as return from retrofit2) so when I show the list in RecyclerView there will be no duplicates.

For better understand of what i mean:
I have `MainActivity` which have `MainViewModel`, in `MainViewModel` i have `CharacterRepository` reference which know how to load data from web as (`Call<CaharacterResponse> / Observable<CharacterResponse>`) and load method from local DB `Livedata<List<Character>>` (this is list of Characters which marked as favorite by user).
what i want is when user load the application both the web and the local data will be loaded and then results will be filtered to remove duplicates.
*CharacterResponse have extra fields about web call result and one of the fields is List.

```
@Dao
public interface CharacterDao {

  @Query("SELECT * FROM character ORDER BY name")
  LiveData<List<Character>> getAllFavoriteCharacters();

....
}

public interface ExampleClient {

  String BASE_URL = "http://gateway.example.com/public/";

  @GET("characters/{id}")
  Call<CharacterResponse> getCharacter(@Path("id")int id);


  @GET("characters")
  Call<CharacterResponse> getCharacters(@Query("limit") @Nullable Integer limit);

  Observable<CharacterResponse> getCharacters();
}
```

Comment: Could you share the relevant code?

Comment: @Anatolii i edited the question

Answer (score 0):

In order to handle both `LiveData` and `Observable` in one way you can adapt them into each other by [LiveDataReactiveStreams](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/LiveDataReactiveStreams) and `Observable.fromPublisher()`.

Then you'll have 2 `Observables` which provides data - one from web and other from local DB.

- You could merge 2 lists by `Observable.concatArrayEager` and then resolve duplicates, probably you'll want some resolving strategy because you need to decide what data is most valid especially in terms of access from different devices,
- Or you can merge local with remote

  `local.mergeWith(remote)
      .collect(() -> new HashSet<Integer>(), (set, v) -> set.add(v))
      .flatMap(Observable::from)
      .subscribe(System.out::println);`
- Or you could use [distinct](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/distinct.html) operator to remove duplicates from `Observable`